# How to write a for in for loop with nrow?

Tags: r

I have a dataset called "trip", including 900,000 records, showing trips. I have a column called "ID", which shows the person ID for an individual. However, here is the point. One individual might have 1 trip, so there is just one record for that ID, but another person might have 7 trips, resulting in 7 rows (with the same ID). Then, I have a column called "transport mode", which can have the values of 1 (for car), 2 (for public transport), 3 (for walk), and 4 (for bike) showing different transport options. Here are my variables:

ID: c(30001, 30002, 30002, 30002, 30002, 30002, 30002, 30002)

Then, I have a column called Transport_mode, relating to that IDs (trips)

Transport_mode : c(1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1)

So, I made an empty variable called "public_fr" to show the frequency of public transport trips. I want to write a for loop that counts the number of public transport mode for any ID. So, I tried the following:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(trip))
   {for (j in 1:nrow(trip$ID))
     {if (as.character(trip$Transport_mode[j] == 2)) (trip$public_fr[j] <- trip$public_fr[j] + 1)}
```

This code should give me:

public_fr: c(0, 3)

0: because ID = 30001 has no public transit trip (look at transport mode 1), and 3: because ID = 30002 has three public transport trips (because there are three 2s).However, it does not work. It gives the error of:

Error in 1:nrow(trip$ID) : argument of length 0

Can you help me with that? if there is a similar question answer, please bring the link. Thanks.

Comment: There are a variety of simpler ways to do this in R. It will be easier to demonstrate them if you can share a sample of your data by including in the body of your question the output of `dput(head(trip))`.

Comment: The tidyverse way to do this would be `library(tidyverse); trip %>% count(ID, transport_mode)` which would count how many of each mode for each id, or `trip %>% filter(transport_mode == 3) %>% count(ID)` to just see the number of public transport trips per ID.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in base R using `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(trip$Transport_mode == 2, list(trip$ID), sum)$x
[1] 0 3
```

Comment: Thanks @G5W. Yes It workde for me with a litttle modification .

Answer (score 2):

If `trip` is given by the code in the Note at the end then this gives a table of counts of ID vs. mode:

```
table(trip)
```

giving:

```
       Transport_mode
ID      1 2 3 4
  30001 1 0 0 0
  30002 1 3 1 1
```

### Note

```
trip <- data.frame(
  ID = c(30001, 30002, 30002, 30002, 30002, 30002, 30002),
  Transport_mode = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because `trip$ID` is just a vector, and vectors don't have rows. `nrow(trip$ID)` will give `NULL`, and `1:NULL` gives the error that you see.

More generally, a `for` loop is a bad way to do this. There are many good ways to do things "by group" in a data frame, `base::aggregate`, or the `dplyr` and `data.table` packages, for example. Here's a `dplyr` version of your code:

```
library(dplyr)
trip %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(public_fr = sum(Transport_mode == 2))
```

In general, `sum(condition)` is a good way to count the number of times a condition is met, like `sum(Transport_mode == 2)` in this case.

If you *really* want to use a `for` loop (you shouldn't---it is harder to write and much slower), you should loop over unique ID values, not over each row:

```
uid = unique(trip$ID)
public_fr = integer(length(uid))
for(i in 1:length(uid)) {
  public_fr[i] = sum(trip[trip$ID == uid[i], "Transport_mode"] == 2)
}
```

The above loop looks at each unique `ID`, pull the Transport_mode values corresponding to that ID, and uses the `sum` trick to count the 2s. But in R, this is a bad way to go. `aggregate`, `dplyr`, or `data.table` are much better.

Comment: I appreciate your attention and full explanation @Gregor .